# Cannot find modules in electron project

Tags: node.js, electron

So the structure of my project currently looks like this:

```
Root
    main.js
    module.js
    ...
    gui-src
        js
            script.js
            test.js
        css
            ...
        ...
```

I want to import `module.js` into `script.js` (`script.js` is part of the renderer process btw). I try to do so using `require('../../module')` but I keep getting errors. What's weird is even if I try to load `require('./test')`, I get errors from there too! `require.main.require()` doesn't give me much luck either...

What exactly is the reason I can't load modules, even ones right next to my source file? Am I misunderstanding require? Or do electron projects work differently than node projects?

Comment: You really should add the actual error messages for each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem: if you want to include your own module in the renderer process in an electron project, you have to use `remote.require(module)`.

Here's more documentation if needed:
https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md